# Exclude specific category posts from being showed in related posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to select related posts from the post's first category, but I need to exclude/skip one of many categories if one of them shows first.

```
<?php 
    // the query
    global $post;
    // We should get the first category of the post
    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    $first_cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
    $the_query = new WP_Query(  $args = array(
            // It should be in the first category of our post:
            'category__in' => array( $first_cat ),
            // Our post should NOT be in the list:
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            // ...And it should fetch 9 posts
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'orderby' => 'desc'
        )); ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `category__not_in` not cutting it?

Comment: Or you want to skip cat id 81 if is the "first" of the categories that the post belongs to?

Comment: @yivi yes, that's precisely that. category__not_in, does not work

Comment: updated my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look for "related" posts unless the category in question is 81, you could do something like:

```
$categories_to_exclude [ 81, 11, 21 ];
$first_cat  = false; 
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
while ( ! empty( $categories ) && false === $first_cat ) {
   if ( in_array($categories[0]->cat_ID, $categories_to_exclude) ) {
      array_shift($categories);
   }
   else {
       $first_cat = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
   }
}
```

You get the categories with `get_the_category`. Then in the `while` loop you skip the first category if it's 81, and look again. If it's not 81 (and you still have categories available), you asign it to `$first_cat` and carry on.

And then you only do the "related" query if you `$first_cat` is not `false`.

Getting confused from your comments, but if what you whant is to exclude posts in one or more categories from your search, you have to use `category__not_in`, which does accept an array. So you could do something like:

```
'category__not_in' => [44, 71, 85],
```

Comment: This is not working.. Let-me try explayin this better: each post can have one or more categories and, if the first category is category 81, I need to exclude all posts inside that category and show only the posts inside the next one.

Comment: Your requirements are a bit weird. So: If the first cat is != 81, you look for posts belonging to that cat (even if they belong to 81 as well). If the first cat == 81, show posts belonging to the "next" cat -let's say 72- (so far, this is what my code covers) but also EXCLUDE any posts that belong to 81. So `category__in` 72 and `category__not_in` 81. Like that?

Comment: If the loop is on a post with categories 81,71,27 => it must skip category 81 and look for related posts in category 71

Comment: That's what my answer does.

Comment: With the bonus that if the post belongs only to 81 you get to skip the search for related posts. Added a bit of explaining. Do you understand it now?

Comment: yes, you right (I haven't deleted the cache... sorry). Can an array be included in `$categories[0]->cat_ID == (here)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131526/discussion-between-yivi-and-alex).

Comment: I don't understand your last question. But then my code solves your problem?

Comment: can it be included and array of cats to exclude if they are the first category? like this: `array(81,72,34, etc...)`

Comment: Still don't understand it. Please, rephrase your question and provide a better example.

Comment: right now the code only exclude category 81 if it's the first category. My question is: Can I exclude more than one category? Perhaps in an array, like this: `array(81,72,34, etc...)`?

Comment: Edit your original question with more detail and examples. As it stands, I can't do anything else, sorry.

Comment: Just imagine this: I alter your code to exclude posts from categories contained in an array: `if ( $categories[0]->cat_ID == array(81,72,34, etc...)) {` Why is this change not working?

Comment: `$categories[0]->cat_ID ` will be an integer, not an array. If you want to skip one of many categories, please edit your original question.